# Visualization Issue when Overlapping Change Detection Map and Shapefile in Python using Rasterio and Matplotlib

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, visualisation, matplotlib

I'm encountering a visualization problem while attempting to overlap a change detection map with a shapefile using Python, Rasterio, and Matplotlib. The change detection map is generated from a matrix containing values of -1, 0, and 1, and it has been exported as a GeoTiff using GDAL. Additionally, I have a shapefile outlining the study area.

When I plot the layers separately, I can see both the change detection map and the shapefile, as shown below:
[image]

However, when I try to overlap these two layers, I'm unable to visualize anything on the map:

```
data = rasterio.open('./dif_2021_2011.tif')
f, ax = plt.subplots()
rasterplot.show(
    data,  # plot raster
    extent=data.bounds,
    ax=ax,
    cmap='seismic'

)
# plot shapefiles
gdf.plot(ax=ax,alpha=0.4, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm confident that this is not a georeferencing problem, as both layers are in the same coordinate reference system.

What steps or parameters can I adjust to improve the visualization and make both layers visible in the overlapped map?

Comment: The bounds are very different in your 1st image. The change detection map looks like it is not georeferenced.